# Can't resolve 'path' in 'path' using description file: samplepath/package.json - Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, path

I'm trying to run npm run build on files I've merged for a website. Unfortunately I always get this error. I think it has something to do with the paths but I'm not that good in JS/React to see where the error is.

**Important part of the Index.html:**

```
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  </body>
```

**Index.jsx**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import App from "./components/App.jsx";

const init = async () => {};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

init();
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

function initCanisterEnv() {
  let localCanisters, prodCanisters;
  try {
    localCanisters = require(path.resolve(
      ".dfx",
      "local",
      "canister_ids.json"
    ));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("No local canister_ids.json found. Continuing production");
  }
  try {
    prodCanisters = require(path.resolve("canister_ids.json"));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing with local");
  }

  const network =
    process.env.DFX_NETWORK ||
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "ic" : "local");

  const canisterConfig = network === "local" ? localCanisters : prodCanisters;

  return Object.entries(canisterConfig).reduce((prev, current) => {
    const [canisterName, canisterDetails] = current;
    prev[canisterName.toUpperCase() + "_CANISTER_ID"] =
      canisterDetails[network];
    return prev;
  }, {});
}
const canisterEnvVariables = initCanisterEnv();

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const frontendDirectory = "websitetwo_frontend";

const frontend_entry = path.join("src", frontendDirectory, "src", "index.html");

module.exports = {
  target: "web",
  mode: isDevelopment ? "development" : "production",
  entry: {
    index: path.join(__dirname, frontend_entry).replace(/\.html$/, ".js"),
  },
  devtool: isDevelopment ? "source-map" : false,
  optimization: {
    minimize: !isDevelopment,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx"],
    fallback: {
      assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
      buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
      events: require.resolve("events/"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify/"),
      util: require.resolve("util/"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", frontendDirectory),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, frontend_entry),
      cache: false,
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: "development",
      ...canisterEnvVariables,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: [require.resolve("buffer/"), "Buffer"],
      process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
    }),
  ],
  // proxy /api to port 8000 during development
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/api": "/api",
        },
      },
    },
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", frontendDirectory, "assets"),
    hot: true,
    watchFiles: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src", frontendDirectory)],
    liveReload: true,
  },
};
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca7kC.png)

I have already searched for the error but it didnt solved it. What is wrong? Thank you for the help!